# Printing keys and values of a dictionary created from excel using xlrd

Tags: python, excel, dictionary, printing, xlrd

```
import xlrd
import os

wb = xlrd.open_workbook (os.path.expanduser("~/Documents/Python/HRCQ determination TABLE.xls"))
sheet = wb.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')


sheetdict = {}

#build ductionary3
for rownum in range(sheet.nrows):
    sheetdict[sheet.cell(rownum,0)] = [sheet.cell(rownum,1)]

#test print dictionary in format: Co-60 - 16 Ci
for keys,values in sheetdict.items():
    print(keys,values)
```

The output of this code ends up being

```
text:'AC225' [number:0.16]
text:'AC227' [number:0.0024]
text:'AC228' [number:14.0]
text:'AG105' [number:54.0]
text:'AG108M' [number:19.0]
text:'AG110M' [number:11.0]
```

etc.

I can't figure out where the text: and [number: ____] are coming from. I think they are actually part of the data being stored in the dictionary from excel, but I can't figure out how to remove it or what excel is doing that's causing it.

I'm very new to Python (coding in general) so all help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Calling the `.cell` method of a `Sheet` object in `xlrd` actually returns a `Cell` object. This `Cell` object is not exactly the value that you are looking. If you need the value itself, you will need to access it with the `.value` attribute of the `Cell` object. In summary, instead of `sheetdict[sheet.cell(rownum,0)] = [sheet.cell(rownum,1)]`, you need to specifically access the `.value` attribute of the `Cell` objects with `sheetdict[sheet.cell(rownum,0).value] = [sheet.cell(rownum,1).value]`.

So, your script would be:

```
import xlrd
import os

wb = xlrd.open_workbook (os.path.expanduser("~/Documents/Python/HRCQ determination TABLE.xls"))
sheet = wb.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')


sheetdict = {}

#build ductionary3
for rownum in range(sheet.nrows):
    sheetdict[sheet.cell(rownum,0).value] = [sheet.cell(rownum,1).value]

#test print dictionary in format: Co-60 - 16 Ci
for keys,values in sheetdict.items():
    print(keys,values)
```

Also, to avoid having to deal with `Cell` object you can access the values directly by using the `.col_values` method of the `Sheet` object for each of the two columns (0 and 1) that you're working with. This will generate two lists of values that you can `zip` together and convert into a `dictionary`. The following is a tweaked version of the script above:

```
import xlrd
import os

wb = xlrd.open_workbook (os.path.expanduser("~/Documents/Python/HRCQ determination TABLE.xls"))
sheet = wb.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

# get column values, zip them together and convert the output into a dictionary
sheetdict = dict(zip(*[sheet.col_values(i) for i in range(2)]))

for keys,values in sheetdict.items():
    print(keys,values)
```

I hope this helps.